# I'm a week old in SQL. I don't understand this error, "ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'S.hacker_id' in 'field list'"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT submission_date, COUNT(hacker_id)
FROM (SELECT S.submission_date, COUNT(DISTINCT S.hacker_id) FROM Submissions S
      GROUP BY S.submission_date) TMP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 14;
```

Can anyone explain what is causing the error. Sorry for this trivial question.
The dataset has 15 dates. Each day hackers submit multiple challenges. I want to query the unique hackers that submit at-least 1 query each day. My approach is... with sub-query, I will eliminate the duplicates on a single day. And then the main query will give me the hacker_id which appears on all the 15 days.

Comment: Add an alias `hacker_id` next to the `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` so the outer `SELECT` can find this field

Comment: I'd run the inner query first and post that output. It's a small mistake but its unclear wher without seeing the output. Plus, I think you need to alias the output of count(distinct()).

Comment: @tonypdmtr ```COUNT(DISTINCT S.hacker_id)``` already has an alias. I don't understand.

Comment: @Kartik: No, it does not. `COUNT()` is not an alias. You have no column `s.hackeri_id` returned from that, which you can see yourself by just running the inner SQL statement. Also, you don't need to repeat `COUNT(hacker_id)` in the outer statement, as you've already counted them in the inner statement.

Comment: Now, I understand what you guys are trying to convey with the add an alias.

Comment: But looks like it cannot find the column `hacker_id` in `submissions` table. Please, provide table structure

Comment: Also the query is a bit confusing: you request the number of distinct identifiers, but also the identifiers themselves (so count(distinct...)` per identifier will definitely be 1). What is the question this query tries to answer?

Comment: The dataset has 15 dates. Each day hackers submit multiple challenges. I want to query the unique hackers that submit at-least 1 query each day.
My approach is... with sub-query, I will eliminate the duplicates on a single day. And then the main query will give me the hacker_id which appears on all the 15 days.

Comment: Which hackkerrank question is this? Mind sharing the link?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/problem?isFullScreen=true

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT submission_date, COUNT(hacker_id)
FROM (SELECT S.submission_date, COUNT(DISTINCT S.hacker_id)
      FROM Submissions S
      GROUP BY S.submission_date
     ) TMP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 14;
```

There are several things wrong with the query:

1. `COUNT(DISTINCT S.hacker_id)` is in a subquery, but you haven't assigned a name to that.
2. The outer query has an aggregation function, `COUNT()`, but no `GROUP BY`.
3. The outer query has `HAVING`, which is normally used to filter after a `GROUP BY`.  But without a `GROUP BY` it doesn't make sense.

It is unclear what you want to do, so I cannot advise on how to fix these problems.  Well, except for the first one.

If you wanted dates with more than 14 different hacker ids, you would use:

```
SELECT S.submission_date, COUNT(DISTINCT S.hacker_id) as num_hacker_ids
FROM Submissions S
GROUP BY S.submission_date
HAVING num_hacker_ids > 14;
```

Comment: The dataset has 15 dates. Each day hackers submit multiple challenges. I want to query the unique hackers that submit at-least 1 query each day. My approach is... with sub-query, I will eliminate the duplicates on a single day. And then the main query will give me the hacker_id which appears on all the 15 days.

Comment: @Kartik . . . You need to explain this in the *question*.  Not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to query the unique hackers that submit at-least 1 query each
> day

```
SELECT hacker_id 
FROM Submissions
GROUP BY hacker_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT submission_date) > 14
```

You should group by hacker and count distinct days for him